# for floating point x, is x==numpy.linspace(x,y,n)[0] always True?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

Note that I am asking about the **end points** of numpy.linspace. The functions is guaranteed to return an array that includes the end points. But are the end points guaranteed to be floating point identical to the arguments supplied to the function?

Reason for asking - pure curiosity. Unless someone can think of a good reason to count on this behavior?
Thanks.

Comment: Well that's an interesting question. I suppose a definition of `floating point identity` would probably make it easier to tackle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an excerpt from the [definition of np.linspace](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/function_base.py#L9):

```
def linspace(start, stop, num=50, endpoint=True, retstep=False):
    ...
    if endpoint:
        if num == 1:
            return array([float(start)])
        step = (stop-start)/float((num-1))
        y = _nx.arange(0, num) * step + start   #<-- the first point is `start`
        y[-1] = stop   # <-- the last point is `stop`
    ...
    return y
```

So yes, when `endpoints` is True, the endpoints returned will be exactly equal to `start` and `stop`.

---

Note that even if `endpoints=True` (which it is by default), `np.linspace` may not return the endpoints if `num` is less than 2:

```
In [8]: np.linspace(0, 1, num=0)
Out[8]: array([], dtype=float64)

In [9]: np.linspace(0, 1, num=1)
Out[9]: array([ 0.])
```